# How can scheduleAtFixedRate run with just 1 thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, schedule

I created a schedule work with scheduleAtFixedRate, and the thread I set 2 ways to execute, 1、

1. Thread.sleep(10000);
2. Thread.sleep(200);

when I run this code, it will execute with a 2s delay, but when `a==3`, the thread sleep 10s, and then, there will exclude 5 thread immediately， How can I just run 1 thread but not 5?

```
public class Words {
    private int a =0;

    public void init(){
        ScheduledExecutorService executor   = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Date d = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat sbf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
                System.out.println(sbf.format(d));
                try {
                    if (a == 3) {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }
                    a += 1;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Words words = new Words();
        words.init();

    }

}
```

[image]

Maybe the thread will execute very long, but I don't want the `scheduleAtFixedRate` to execute a lot of threads like the phenomenon I've said, How can the scheduleAtFixedRate just run 1 thread? thank you

Comment: It's not "executing lots of threads". It's just executing the scheduled events that were missed due to your 10 second sleep.

Comment: In fact the reason you are seeing that is because you're using a single thread which gets blocked by your 10s sleep and prevents other scheduled events from being executed. If you want the events to be executed in time, you should be using more threads, not less. Maybe you want `scheduleWithFixedDelay` instead?

Comment: Or you have to make another `scheduleAtFixedRate` for `10s` thread

Comment: Documentation: "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.". (From question) *and then, there will exclude 5 thread immediately* - they won't, you can see the 200ms delay between the logs.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I just want 1 thread, and the time the thread finished is not the same. The normal operation is 1s, the abnormal one is maybe 10s, I dont want the thread run 5 times after the abnormal one finished, I just want run 1 times and after 2s run anather one, what should I do, thank you very much.